# Passing query string in a GET request, express converts '+' character in query string into space. How to avoid this?

Tags: node.js, express, http, get, urlencode

I am passing certain parameters in query string in a GET request let's say
HOST?email=john**+**1@gmail.com. When I try to access these in node express server through req.query.email, I get the value 'john 1@gmail.com'. Express is converting '**+**' character into space character. Is there a way that I can stop this encoding?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the literal + sign, you need to URL encode it to %2b, e.g.

```
HOST?email=john**%2b1@gmail.com.
```

That will decoded correctly by express, e.g.

```
req.query.email: john**+1@gmail.com.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can use encodeURIComponent() to convert '+' character into %2B. But is there a way that I can halt the parsing of '+' character to ' ' at the level of express. I do not want to do this at the client level or URL level.

Comment: You could try require('url').parse(req.url).query. This would give the whole query string though.

Comment: Yeah!. But then I will have to split() the string with '&' delimiter. Then again split() each string with '=' delimiter.